# Can't save changes to attribute table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table

I have a table with over 19000 points. One of the attributes of each point is either 0 or 1. However, there are 7 points with NULL. I would like to change these NULL to 1's.

When I open the `Attribute Table` and manually change the values, I can't save my changes. Every `Save` button is greyed-out. Therefore when I refresh all the values have reverted to their original ones.

How can I fix this? Or is there another way to do it? (I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9,1.)

Edit: I have tried the "Calculate Field" tool. Unfortunately, I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'.

The table wasn't open or being edited anywhere else.

I managed to circumvent the problem by just loading and changing the data in Qgis and then exporting it.

Comment: Have you tried using the "Calculate Field" tool instead of manually replacing the values?

Comment: This can happen if the table is open elsewhere and being edited. Is this a shapefile, feature class, or something else?

Comment: It is a geopackage. I don't have it open anywhere else.

Comment: I have tried the "Calculate Field" tool. Unfortunately, I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'.

Comment: Have you turned on editing on the edit tab?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Your last sentence appears to be an answer, rather than part of the question.

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure I'd call that an answer - it worked around the problem, but potentially the problem still exists.

Comment: Then I would argue that it is not necessary to include in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try selecting the attributes by going to the Map Tab, "Select By Attributes" after that go to the Edit tab opening the "Attributes" Menu under Selection and editing the attributes there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround If you keep the editing fields table open and then in the table on the top ribbon click add a new field. A message will pop up asking if you want to save or delete edits. There you can save your edits.

Comment: selecting another record in the table also sometimes wakes up the save button.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute Table -> Calculate Field (Python)

```
1 if !field_name! is None else !field_name!
```

Answer (score 0):

This would occur if the dataset was locked or in use somewhere else. This has caused me pain in the past. I would suggest clearing all selections, closing all ArcGIS Pro windows, saving your document, then re-opening it. Then when you re-open, don't do anything but go straight to those records, edit them, then save them.